# Django math interpreter field

Tags: python, django

I've been using a Django app which makes me do a lot of multiplication before entering data into the decimal field blanks. It would save me a ton of time to be able to write a python expression in each box, such as 4*12, and have the database store the value 48.

Do you know of any preexisting fields that would allow this sort of data entry, or at least pull in the data and do some back end processing before storing the data?

Thanks!

Comment: pretty dangerous territory in terms of security. if you find any solution, make sure that it does not just execute the statements to calculate the values since that could become a security vulnerability. maybe it expects the input from users in particular format (sort of like json but for math), validates it first and then calculates the value.

Comment: Using [sympy](http://www.sympygamma.com/) to process the field might fit your needs.

Comment: If literally all you want is multiplication, the safest and simplest thing to do is probably something like `reduce(mul, map(int, s.split('*'))`.

Comment: If you need general expressions, you're probably better off writing an expression parser for the small subset of Python that you need. (You could use something like PyParsing, or a custom op-precedence parser, or just use `ast.parse` and then interpret the tree.)

Comment: You _could_ try to sanitize the input (even something as simple as `all(c in '0123456789 +-*/()' for c in s)` might work) and call `eval` only if it passes, but it's very easy to miss a dangerous case when building things that way. (For example, if you want to add the ability to handle hex, just add `xabcdef` to the legal input, and everything works, right? Except that now the `eval` could end up calling a function named `axe` or `face`, so your sanitization is no longer safe.)

Comment: Honestly, I only need multiplication. I'm putting in total cost, where I always have cost per item and quantity. Plus, only two people have access to the interface, so I think it's probably not a security issue?